# How can I use X.509 cross signing to replace a CA?

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority, openssl, x.509

I have a self-signed CA that I want to rotate the key for. I want to use [cross-signing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509#Example_2:_CA_certificate_renewal) to facilitate this, with gradual replacement of the certificate on the clients so they can still communicate.

I'm using [cfssl](https://github.com/cloudflare/cfssl), but can't figure out practically how to get this to work. For testing purposes I've generated two new CAs with identical CNs and cross-signed them:

```
cfssl gencert -initca ca-csr-A.json | cfssljson -bare ca-A
cfssl gencert -initca ca-csr-B.json | cfssljson -bare ca-B

cfssl sign -ca ca-A.pem -ca-key ca-A-key.pem -config ca-config.json ca-B.csr | cfssljson -bare ca-B-by-A
cfssl sign -ca ca-B.pem -ca-key ca-B-key.pem -config ca-config.json ca-A.csr | cfssljson -bare ca-A-by-B
```

I've then created a new client certificate, signed with A's private key and the A certificate cross-signed by B:

```
cfssl gencert -ca=ca-A-by-B.pem -ca-key=ca-A-key.pem -config=ca-config.json child-csr.json | cfssljson -bare child
```

I've then tried to verify (using `openssl verify`) the new client certificate with either original A, original B or either of the cross-signed CAs, but can't work out the incantation. I've tried bundling `ca-A-by-B.pem` and `ca-B.pem`, and tried bundling the client with `ca-A-by-B.pem` as an intermediary, but they don't work either.

I think I missing something obvious, or just misunderstanding cross-signing completely. Is this even possible?

Comment: Can you show the `openssl verify` command? I suspect that's where your problem is.

Comment: It seems odd that your end-entity is issued by `ca-A-by-B`, shouldn't it be issued by the `ca-A` self-signed root cert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*These answers might be helpful:*

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/33365131/1907046
- [How to properly create and use cross-signed CAs and certificates](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/133221/61443)

---

Alright, so the idea would be to place the cross-certs into the trust stores of your clients so that during cert validation they can path-build from the CA they don't trust to the one they do.

Your test-scenario is that you have an **end-entity** cert issued by `ca-A`, and a **client** verifier who only trusts `ca-B`.  You also have a `ca-A-by-B` cross-cert that you can give to the client so that it can path-build between the two CAs.  I believe the correct openssl command-line incantation to simulate that would be:

- `-CAfile ca-B.pem` so that ca-B is "in the trust store".
- `-untrusted ca-A-by-B.pem` so that the verifier is aware that it can use that cert for path-building, but doesn't consider it a trusted root.
- `< (cat ca-A.pem child.pem)` simulate receiving a cert-bundle containing the end-entity cert and its issuer (ca-A).

all together:

```
openssl verify -verbose -CAfile ca-B.pem -untrusted ca-A-by-B.pem < (cat ca-A.pem child.pem)
```

I haven't actually tried this cause I'm too lazy to generate test certs, but let me know if it helps (or if I need to make corrections).

Comment: That works, but I do still get:

    `error 18 at 0 depth lookup:self signed certificate 
    OK`

Which I assume is it trying to validate the first cert in the bundle.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hmm, looks like OpenSSL is picky that the CN of each cert in the chain be different? I wonder if openssl just doesn't support link certs (a cross-cert from a CA to itself on a new key).  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726138/openssl-error-18-at-0-depth-lookupself-signed-certificate?lq=1